# Change date on query based on result of a colomn from another table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have an sql query like this:

```
WITH CUR_DATE AS(
 SELECT to_date(cur_value, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS cur_value
 FROM PARAMS
 WHERE id = 'CURRENT_SERVER_DATE'
)
SELECT 
   cur_date.cur_value - 1 as date_cal,
   iar.allocation_date
FROM POS
 CROSS JOIN CUR_DATE
 INNER JOIN REFERENCE
   ON RC.reference_id = REFERENCE.id
```

and I wish to modify the value of 'date_cal' upon the result of 'GENERATION_TYPE' from another query :

```
select distinct(GENERATION_TYPE) 
 from VVV_PICKING_HIST where CREATION_DATE =    (select MAX(CREATION_DATE)
 from VVV_PICKING_HIST
```

Means that if GENERATION_TYPE = "NO" I leave cur_date.cur_value - 1 otherwise I remove the -1 and I'll have

```
cur_date.cur_value as date_cal
```

I don't know how to merge the two queries and use for example

```
CASE WHEN GENERATION_TYPE = "NO" 
THEN cur_date.cur_value - 1 AS DATE_CAL  ELSE cur_date.cur_value AS DATE_CAL
```

Comment: What is the relations between those tables?

Comment: There is no relation this is the problem. VVV_PICKING_HIST alows me to know if an engine has run or no and upon that result I have to change values of date on my query

Comment: What does it return? only 'YES' or 'NO' (and only 1 time) or multiple output set?

Comment: only 'YES' or 'NO'. 1 row 1 colomn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CUR_DATE AS(
 SELECT to_date(cur_value, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS cur_value
 FROM PARAMS
 WHERE id = 'CURRENT_SERVER_DATE'
)
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN GENERATION_TYPE = "NO" 
        THEN cur_date.cur_value - 1 
        ELSE cur_date.cur_value end as date_cal,
   iar.allocation_date
FROM POS
 CROSS JOIN CUR_DATE
 INNER JOIN REFERENCE
   ON RC.reference_id = REFERENCE.id
 INNER JOIN(select distinct(GENERATION_TYPE) as GENERATION_TYPE
            from VVV_PICKING_HIST where CREATION_DATE = (select MAX(CREATION_DATE)
                                                         from VVV_PICKING_HIST))
   ON(1=1)
```